# filter data passed into an underscore template

Tags: underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

My page has 5 different tabs.

I have a templateData object that contains multiple objects.

I would like to pass into each tab a list of objects within my templateData object that match a certain criteria.

e.g

```
$("#cat-37").append(template(_.where(templateData.listItems, {cat_group: "37"})));
```

Sample object within my templateData object

```
    {cat_group:"37",
skill_id:"56",
skill_title:"Neutral/Stable Position",
status:"open",
tunnel:"Denver"}
```

I can get the _.where() function to work externally but there is something about the format that that the template() function requires that is getting tripped up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to pass the data in as an object.

```
//list of objects
var data = _.where(templateData.listItems, {cat_group: "37"});
$("#cat-37").append(template({data:data}));
```

Then in your template

```
<script type="text/template" id="myTemplate">
<% _.each(data,function(d){ %>
    //iterate thru data and do your thing
<% }) %>
</script>
```